# How to fix double ssh banner?

Tags: server, ssh

I don't really know what happened, but since a few days ago every time I ssh into my server I got this

```
λ ssh doc@myserver
doc@myserver's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-33-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 * MicroK8s gets a native Windows installer and command-line integration.

     https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-installers-windows-and-macos

0 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.

Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2025.
Last login: Thu Jun  4 10:35:26 2020 from 1.2.3.4
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-33-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 * MicroK8s gets a native Windows installer and command-line integration.

     https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-installers-windows-and-macos

0 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.

Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2025.
Last login: Thu Jun  4 10:35:26 2020 from 1.2.3.4
doc@myserver:~$
```

How can I fix this? (also, I like having a glance over packages updates, security updates and last login info, but I couldn't care a less about microk8s news...)

thank you!

Comment: Instead of disabling it I edited the config to `URLS="https://wttr.in/location?0&Q&T"`, now I get the weather instead of ads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the ubuntu motd, you can disable it in

> /etc/default/motd-news

just change ENABLED=1 from 1 to 0

By doing a

```
grep -ERi "motd" /etc
```

we can see how linux has become a mess!

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config there is a "PrintMotd no" option, but even if it is set to no, there is a motd displayed indeed.

In /etc/update-motd.d/ there are 11 files!

There are a few things related to motd in 
/etc/pam.d/sshd and in /etc/pam.d/login

Probably by reviewing those last 2 files, you'll get a clue how to fix your issue.

good luck ;)